# Is possible optimize json.net schema with JSchemaValidatingReader to deserialize in object in same read of stream?

Tags: c#, json.net, schema, jsonschema

I'm trying a poc.
Is possible optimize json.net schema  with JSchemaValidatingReader to deserialize in object in same read of stream?

In otherworld

```
string schemaJson = @"{
      'description': 'A person',
      'type': 'object',
      'properties': {
        'name': {'type': 'string'},
        'hobbies': {
          'type': 'array',
          'items': {'type': 'string'}
        }
      }
    }";

JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

using (StreamReader s = File.OpenText(@"c:\bigdata.json"))
using (JSchemaValidatingReader reader = new JSchemaValidatingReader(new JsonTextReader(s)))
{
    reader.Schema = schema;
    reader.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, args) => { Console.WriteLine(args.Message); };

    //Deserialize json while validating
    while (reader.Read())
    {
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`JSchemaValidatingReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JSchemaValidatingReader.htm) is a subclass of [`JsonReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm), so you can use it to deserialize by passing it to [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize.htm):

```
using (var s = File.OpenText(@"c:\bigdata.json"))
using (var baseReader = new JsonTextReader(s))
using (var reader = new JSchemaValidatingReader(baseReader))
{
    reader.Schema = schema;
    reader.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, args) => { Console.WriteLine(args.Message); };

    root = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<RootObject>(reader);
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pamnbB).

Related documentation: [Validate JSON with JSchemaValidatingReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/JsonValidatingReaderAndSerializer.htm).