# How to validate if JObject is of specific type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to figure out if JObject has the right attributes to match CustomObject type. I am using JObject.ToObject with hopes that it would fail if attributes do not match CustomObject, but instead it still creates CustomObject with all properties null.

Anyway I can validate it before I call ToObject?

```
class CustomObject
{
  string fname;
  string lname;
}

void test()
{
  string json = "{\"User\": \"Hello\"}";
  JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);

  CustomObject custObj = null;


  // this always creates CustomObject instance
  // I need to validate that jsonObj has valid attributes that match CustomObject
  custObj = JObject.ToObject<CustomObject>();
```

Comment: What should happen if the JSON is `{ "fname": "Joe" }`?  Is that a failure condition, due to the fact that `lname` is not in the JSON, or is it a success since there are no properties in the JSON which do not match the class?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: You can use the `[JsonRequiredAttribute]`:

```
class CustomObject
{
    [JsonRequiredAttribute]
    string fname;
    [JsonRequiredAttribute]
    string lname;
}
```

Or, you can use [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/) to validate that:

```
var schema = JSchema.Parse(@"{ 
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'fname': { 'type': 'string' },
        'lname': { 'type': 'string' }
    },
    'additionalProperties': false,
    'required': ['name', 'email']
}");
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse("{\"User\": \"Hello\"}");

// throws if not valid
jsonObj.Validate(schema);

// or, if you want to handle it yourself
if (!jsonObj.IsValid(schema, out IList<ValidationError> errors))
{
    // ...
}

// if all pass
var custObj = jsonObj.ToObject<CustomObject>();
```

Comment: You can validate while deserializing if you want, and throw an exception from within the `ValidationEventHandler`.  See: [Is possible optimize json.net schema with JSchemaValidatingReader to deserialize in object in same read of stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40306330/3744182).  Also, I think your schema may be wrong, it should be `'required': ['fname', 'lname']`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CustomObject
{
    [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
    string fname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LastName")]
    string lname { get; set; }
}
```

```
public void Test()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> collection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        collection.Add("FirstName", "Test");
        collection.Add("LastName", "1234");
        JObject jsobObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));

        CustomObject custObj = new CustomObject();

        if (jsobObj != null)
        {
            if (jsobObj.Property("FirstName") != null && jsobObj.Property("LastName") != null)
            {
                custObj = jsobObj.ToObject<CustomObject>();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: how do I make FirstName and LastName case insensitive?

Comment: When you are doing your string checks.....use ```String.Compare(varA, varB, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)```

Comment: Last comment was in VB, but in c# it's just ```string.Compare()```.  But right now, the properties are case insensitive...they can be upper or lowercase.  You're wanting all logic checks that look at the properties to ignore the casing, but you have to specify that when you do the logic check.

Comment: Another option... ```ToLower()``` and ```ToUpper()```. So when you do a check ```if (fname.ToLower() == myVariable.ToLower())``` you are setting the case.  But honestly, I think the ```string.Compare()``` is the cleanest and most effective because of the InvariantCulture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.SelectToken()` to get a specific object out of a larger json with multiple different objects.

For your specific example, it would look like this.

```
custObj = (CustomObject)jsonObj.SelectToken("CustomObject");
```

You're going to cast the selected token to `CustomObject`, then assign it to your `custObj` variable.

From the [documentation on SelectToken()](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm), a null reference is created if a token couldn't be found in the given JObject.