# Can I validate and deserialize in a single operation?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I am reading a `string` asynchronously from an `HttpRequestData` instance (Azure Function HttpTrigger). I then use `JObject.Parse`, then I execute the `IsValid()` method on the `JObject`, and then if it is valid I convert the `JObject` to my target type.

This seems like a lot of steps. Can I instead have the validation and deserialization happen in a single step?

Also: Is there a way to have it use case-insensitive property names?

```cs
        SendMessageCommand? payload = null;
        IList<string> validationErrors = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            string? payloadJson = await httpRequest.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (payloadJson is null)
                validationErrors.Add("Request is null");
            else
            {
                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(payloadJson!);
                if (jsonObject.IsValid(SchemaValidator, out validationErrors))
                    payload = jsonObject.ToObject<SendMessageCommand>();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            payload = null;
        }

        if (payload is null)
        {
            HttpResponseData badResponse = httpRequest.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            await badResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(validationErrors);
            return badResponse;
        }
```

Comment: Been a while since I looked a this but I believe so.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312384/3744182) to [Is possible optimize json.net schema with JSchemaValidatingReader to deserialize in object in same read of stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40306330/3744182).

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) and as [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) suggested you can use the `JSchemaValidatingReader` directly instead of calling the `IsValid` or `Validate` method.

```
using var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(payloadJson));
using var validatingReader = new JSchemaValidatingReader(reader) { Schema = dtoSchema };
var payload = JsonSerializer.Create().Deserialize<SendMessageCommand>(validatingReader);
```

If you want to capture validation errors then you have to add a handler for the `ValidationEventHandler`:

```
validatingReader.ValidationEventHandler += (_, args) => messages.Add(args.Message);
```

Please bear in mind that if you don't provide a delegate for the `ValidationEventHandler` then the `Deserialize` will throw an `JSchemaValidationException` if the payload is violating the schema.

---

Dotnet Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8O4Qir

Comment: Ohh... I did not see that you have already confirmed that it's working...

Comment: It's still good to have an answer posted. Thank you!